# Unsorted array - Getting index from next higher value | Complexity O(n), PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, search, complexity-theory

I search a PHP algorithmus of **complexity O(n)**. I have an array out of integer and I want for every element the index number of the nearest bigger value than this or -1 if it does not exist.
**Note:** Every value is unique.

**Example**:

```
$arr = [7, 3, 5, 4];
$result = [-1, 3, 0, 2];
```

Explanation:

- 7 has no bigger value => -1
- 3 next bigger value 4 => 3
- 5 next bigger value 7 => 0
- 4 next bigger value 5 => 2

#### Solution which works fine but it hat O(n²):

```
function follows ($arr, $index) {
    $filter = array_filter($arr, function($el) use ($arr, $index) { return $el > $arr[$index]; });
    if (count($filter)===0)
        return -1;
    else
        return array_search(min($filter), $arr);
}

$res = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    $res[] = follows($arr,$i);
}
var_dump($res); // => [-1, 3, 0, 2]
```

#### Solution with O(n) searched

I supposed to use `asort` (in example: `[3, 4, 5, 7]`), so the values are sorted and I can get the original-index of the next element there.
This is part of an idea for it:

```
$arr = [ 7, 3, 5, 4];
asort($arr);
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    echo 'For: ' . $i . ': ' . $arr[$i].'<br>';
}

echo "<br>";

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    echo 'ForEach; ' . $key . ': ' . $val .'<br>';
}

echo '<br><br>' . $arr[2];
```

After the sorting with asort the indexes are the same as you can see with the `for-loop` but within the `forEach-loop` they are sorted new but the indexes are still same.
**Idea:** Take the index from the for-loop get the corresponding index of the forEach-loop increment it by 1 and get the original-index.
**Example:** Index 1 in my array has value 3 and in the for-loop still an index of 1 but in the forEach-loop an index of 0. Getting there the next element (index 1) with value 4 has an original-index of 3.

The last step is easy. Can anybody help to get the missing link from index of for to index of forEach without find?

Comment: Can it be that input array has some equal elements? For example `[7,3,3,5]`?

Comment: No this is not allowed. Every value is maximum once used and here is the 3 twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that doesn't flip the array so can work with any type of array data. It uses a single loop and an `asort` so is `O(n*log(n))`. Once the data is sorted, the `key` function is used to determine the key of the next larger value in a loop; when the loop finishes the final "next" value is set to -1 (since there is no larger value). At this point the output has the correct key/value pairs but not in numeric order (this may be sufficient for your needs):

```
$arr = [7, 3, 5, 4];
asort($arr);
$temp = [];
$count = 1;
$key = key($arr);
while (next($arr) !== false) {
    $temp[$key] = key($arr);
    $key = key($arr);
    $count++;
}
$temp[$key] = -1;
print_r($temp);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [2] => 0
    [0] => -1
)
```

If you need the keys sorted (for example, if you want the entries to be in order when you use a `foreach` loop), you can use another loop, taking advantage of the `$count` variable generated in the above code, to copy the values into a new, ordered array:

```
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $result[] = $temp[$i];
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 2
)
```

If you don't need this, you can remove the computation of `$count` from the first code block.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/o2kWp)

Comment: Thanks that works for me! I could adapt it to my needs.In my case I have for each array-element an interval `[i,j]` with i<j and I had to search for ending (i.e. j) of each interval the index of the interval which starts with j or bigger but there isn't any smaller startpoint of an other interval for this. You brought me to use `array_column` on both index and `asort` after. Than I use `forEach` over the ends and `next` for the starts. By this I can build my result on which I use at the end `ksort`. Demo on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b619f3d17ca05575ce3ee95fede121bea897fb90

Comment: @Sascha your code was indeed quite a bit more complicated! I'm glad you were able to adapt this to be useful.

Comment: Btw. beware of using `while (next($arr))`, better use `while (next($starts)!==false)`. If next($starts) returns `0` you will break though it's an allowed sollution (this takes me tonight some time).

Comment: @Sascha sorry about that! it was a careless mistake. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Don't worry, we all make mistakes and this is one I would probably also have done. From mistakes we learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm iterating array 3 times (array_flip, for, for) and sorting it 1 time (ksort). I do not know how to count complexity... Maybe, count loops as `O(N)` and ksort as `O(N*log(N))`. So the final complexity is `O(N*log(N))`. I can't make it smaller :)

```php
$arr = [7, 3, 5, 4];

$flip = array_flip($arr); // prepare for sort
ksort($flip); // sort

// put results into place
$keys = array_keys($flip);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($flip) - 1; $i++) {
    $flip[$keys[$i]] = $flip[$keys[$i + 1]];
}
$flip[$keys[count($keys) - 1]] = -1;

// finalize results
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    array_push($result, $flip[$arr[$i]]);
}

print_r($result);
```

External link to test: [click](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eaae3c3771c4380ea99b1872c8325b07e9cf38d3)

Comment: Really interesting solution. I need to adapt it to my needs because I simplified it for the question. I have as values objects and my array has sizes up to 10.000 entries.